# regrex in Selenium IDE (Google Chrome extension) did not work

Tags: java, selenium

[image]

I tried to verify text with regrex in Selenium IDE (Google Chrome extension), but it's not working, although I follow step by step in the tutorial.

I test the title element with text value "regrex in Selenium IDE (Google Chrome extension) did not work", regexp is: ^[a-zA-z]

[Dowload file .SIDE here](https://a.uguu.se/FI1T3IUGIWmC_StackOverFlow.side)
[image]

Comment: What is the link of your tutorial? I guess you made typo.

Comment: https://sangbui.com/selenium-ide-regular-expression-pattern/
it's using Selenium IDE for Firefox, not Chrome, regrex not been supported in GG Chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

regrex in Selenium IDE (Google Chrome extension) *worked*, because the value you enter is empty or null string.

> Actual value "" did not match "regexp:^[A-Z0-9+_.-]"

Comment: I have tested this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906136/regrex-in-selenium-ide-google-chrome-extension-did-not-work/62909167
i assert text of the element with xpath, please check my edited paragraph to understand clearly.

Comment: i upload .side file, you can import to Selenium IDE to run test, thanks so much!